# Hangs on application while trying to get connection from access database

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am about to be crazy for this problem for 2 days. I have an application which has one client project(UI), an application server, one client  project( makes some computations using another program).Clients and server communicate with each other using jms. I am trying to connect access database from computation client, Application hangs on while executing following statement of DriverManager class

```
di.driver.connect(url, info);
```

I am able to connect from  server, also UI client with the same code. My system is not distributed .All  Projects are reside in my local environment. So their operating environment same. They use same jdk. Please tel me what can be the problem

I call following function before getting connection.It creates odbc data source.

```
public static void createODBCSource(String dbPath) {

    // ODBC parameters
    String[] argsXP = { "ODBCCONF", "CONFIGDSN",
            "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)",
            "DSN=datasource-db;Server=localhost;Port=3306;DBQ=" + dbPath };
    String[] argsVistaSeven = { "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\odbcconf.exe",
            "CONFIGDSN", "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)",
            "DSN=psa-db;Server=localhost;Port=3306;DBQ=" + dbPath };

    // creating a process for the ODBC
    ProcessBuilder pb = null;
    String version = System.getProperty("os.name");

    if (version.equals("Windows XP")) {
        pb = new ProcessBuilder(argsXP);
    } else if (version.equals("Windows 7")
            || version.equals("Windows Vista")) {
        pb = new ProcessBuilder(argsVistaSeven);
    }

    // starting the process
    pb.directory(new File("."));
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.getInputStream().close();
        p.getOutputStream().close();
        p.getErrorStream().close();
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then I call following function to get connection

private static final String URL_MS_ACCESS = "jdbc:odbc:**datasource-db**";

```
public static Connection connect(String user, String pass, int db) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    if (db == MYSQL) {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_MYSQL);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL_MYSQL, user, pass);
    } else if(db == ACCESS) {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_MS_ACCESS);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL_MS_ACCESS, "", "");
    }
    return conn;
}
```

**EDIT**

Computation Client works by listening jms messages(Implements MessageListener).It does jobs when it receive a jms message from server(onMessage method).  Getting access connection does not work after this point. I do not know how it is logic.I think that is is thread related.

I set log writer of DriverManager to debugging. This is the log written. It hangs SQLAllocConnect. Please show me a way to handle.

```
    JdbcOdbcDriver class loaded
registerDriver: driver[className=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1e88b35]
DriverManager.initialize: jdbc.drivers = null
JDBC DriverManager initialized
registerDriver: driver[className=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver,sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@b655a]
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:romania-db")
    trying driver[className=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1e88b35]
    trying driver[className=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver,sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@b655a]
*Driver.connect (jdbc:odbc:datasource-db)
JDBC to ODBC Bridge: Checking security
No SecurityManager present, assuming trusted application/applet
JDBC to ODBC Bridge 2.0001
Current Date/Time: Fri Jan 18 17:25:53 EET 2013
Loading JdbcOdbc library
Allocating Environment handle (SQLAllocEnv)
hEnv=404691320
Allocating Connection handle (SQLAllocConnect)
hDbc=404691488
Connecting (SQLDriverConnect), hDbc=404691488, szConnStrIn=DSN=datasource-db
```

Comment: I would first try it with manual creation, without `createODBCSource`. As remark: using something different than MS Access would be worth it. Like the embedded DB java Derby.

Comment: Actually , I did this.I created an odbc  from Control Panel/adminitrative tools.But it did not work. I am using output of another program.It outputs the file in mdb format.So I  must use access

Answer (score 0):

I thing Joop advice to first try to use manually created DSN is good. While you use JDBC-ODBC bridge you can monitor ODBC calls via Trace feature than can be enabled from ODBC Manager. This is part of my trace `sql.log` when I connected from Jython to Access using `jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\Nwind.mdb`:

```
*" org.python.u 83c-928 ENTER SQLAllocEnv 
        HENV *              00A6F3F0

*" org.python.u 83c-928 EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV *              0x00A6F3F0 ( 0x044a1c18)

*" org.python.u 83c-928 ENTER SQLAllocConnect 
        HENV                044A1C18
        HDBC *              00A6F350

*" org.python.u 83c-928 EXIT  SQLAllocConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                044A1C18
        HDBC *              0x00A6F350 ( 0x044a1cc0)

*" org.python.u 83c-928 ENTER SQLDriverConnectW 
        HDBC                044A1CC0
        HWND                00000000
        WCHAR *             0x74609110 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x74609110 
        SWORD                        2 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

*" org.python.u 83c-928 EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HDBC                044A1CC0
        HWND                00000000
        WCHAR *             0x74609110 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x74609110 
        SWORD                        2 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>
...
```

As you see there is `ENTER`, `EXIT` pair of each API call so it would be easy to see which API function hung.